# Call method onclick with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to make a simple function that will increase a counter when a click occurs on one of my lis. When I run this, I get an error *addEventListener is not a function.*

HTML:

```
  <ul class="boxes">
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
    <li class="box"></li>
  </ul>
```

JS:

```
     var squares = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

   function MyCounter(el){
            this.turn = 0;

              this.addClick = function() {
                this.turn ++;
                console.log(this.turn);
            };

              el.addEventListener('click', this.addClick(), false);
       }
    var c = new MyCounter(squares);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want one counter per list item or one counter for all?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak just one counter for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    function MyCounter(els){
      this.turn = 0;
    
      this.addClick = function() {
        this.turn++;
        console.log(this.turn);
      };
    
      // old code:
      //el.addEventListener('click', this.addClick(), false);
      // 1. parameter el is a collection of DOM elements, not a single element
      // 2. this.addClick() - calls addClick, resulting in undefined to be passed to addEventListener
      // 3. context inside addClick (if its reference is passed to addEventListener) would be DOM element, not instance of MyCounter
      for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i].addEventListener('click', this.addClick.bind(this), false);
      }
    }
    
    var squares = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    var c = new MyCounter(squares);
```

```css
div.box
{
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin-right:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">A</div>
<div class="box">B</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like of elements, not a single element.

It should be:

`var squares = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[index];`

**For each class element loop**:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach((e) => {
  ...
  e.addEventListener(...)
});
```

Comment: @Igor this solution points out the most likely mistake (which is mistaking the result of `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName`). I do not think it's worth it to go through other stuff like iterating over all class elements to find out the one that is right.

Comment: `squares` is not an array thus `forEach` is not defined. Test it!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir ... you're right, since I didn't want to copy others answers I posted an alternative option

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to add an event listener to a list of elements. Instead you need to loop though them and apply the listener to each single one:

```
function MyCounter(links) {
    var turn = 0;

    function addClick = function() {
        turn ++;
        console.log(turn);
    };

    for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
        links[i].addEventListener('click', addClick(), false);
    }
}
```

This way you have one function that acts as a global counter.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function MyCounter(squares){
    this.turn = 0;

    this.addClick = function() {
        this.turn ++;
        console.log(this.turn);
    };

    var that = this;
    for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
        squares[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
         that.addClick();
        }, false);
    }
}

var squares = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
var c = new MyCounter(squares);
```

```html
<ul class="boxes">
    <li class="box">box</li>
    <li class="box">box</li>
    <li class="box">box</li>
    <li class="box">box</li>
    <li class="box">box</li>
    <li class="box">box</li>
    <li class="box">box</li>
    <li class="box">box</li>
    <li class="box">box</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use this method, if the boxes are filling the size of the ul element (instead of creating several listeners)

```
<ul id="boxes" class="boxes">
        <li class="box"></li>
        <li class="box"></li>
        <li class="box"></li>
        <li class="box"></li>
        <li class="box"></li>
        <li class="box"></li>
        <li class="box"></li>
        <li class="box"></li>
        <li class="box"></li>
      </ul>

    <script>


var squares = document.getElementById("boxes");
squares.addEventListener('click', function (el) {
    if ("HTMLLIElement" === el.target.constructor.name) {
        //counter++
    }
}, true);
    </script>
```